# Error bars in ggplot in middle of bin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a bar plot in ggplot with 2 values for each bin (fold change values from RNA-Seq and qPCR experiments):

```
Gene    FC  expt    se
a   1.02    RNA-Seq 0
b   2.79    RNA-Seq 0
c   1.63    RNA-Seq 0
d   0.84    RNA-Seq 0
e   0.81    RNA-Seq 0
f   1.45    RNA-Seq 0
g   1.27    RNA-Seq 0
h   1.72    RNA-Seq 0
i   2.52    RNA-Seq 0
a   0.84    qPCR    0.16
b   1.92    qPCR    0.15
c   1.14    qPCR    0.78
d   0.47    qPCR    0.76
e   0.95    qPCR    0.26
f   0.32    qPCR    0.51
g   0.92    qPCR    0.39
h   0.97    qPCR    0.61
i   1.73    qPCR    0.77
```

My RNA-Seq values don't have error bars. As such I want to plot a barchart with:

- Error bars that only extend up
- Error bars only for q-PCR bars

I'm not sure where my code (or input format) is going wrong:

```
df <- read.table("stack.txt", header=TRUE)
limits <- aes(ymax = FC + se, ymin = FC)
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.9)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Gene, y=FC)) +
geom_errorbar(limits, position = dodge, width = 0.25) +
geom_bar(aes(fill=expt),colour="black", stat="identity", position = dodge)
```

Which produces:

[image]

As you can see, the error bars are in the middle of each bin, rather than being onto of each bar. Any suggestions/comments would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: `position_dodge(width = <...>)`

Comment: @Roland It's the same question, but the data and answers are different it would seem. At least as far as I can see they don't help me much, whereas the answer provided below does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the `group` parameter to the `aes`, you will get the desired result:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Gene, y=FC, fill=expt, group=expt)) +
  geom_bar(colour="black", stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = FC + se, ymin = FC, group=expt),
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), width = 0.25)
```

this gives:

[image]