# Increase space between bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a [bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452208/error-bars-in-ggplot-in-middle-of-bin):

```
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Gene, y=FC, fill=expt, group=expt))
p <- p + geom_bar(colour="black", stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = FC + se, ymin = FC, group=expt),
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), width = 0.25)
p
```

I want to increase the spacing between bars (for each bin). I've tried messing around with the `position_dodge(width = ...)` but it skews my error bars:

[image]

There are several other questions that relate to this:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040245/how-to-increase-the-space-between-the-bars-in-a-bar-plot-in-ggplot2) has an answer that seems to do the trick (but difficult to implement)
- When I use the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085238/adding-space-between-bars-in-ggplot2) I get the following:

[image]

i.e it seems to increase the between bins, but at the expense of overlapping with the neighbouring bar

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can adjust the width outside of the `position_dodge` as well (in `geom_bar`),

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Gene, y=FC, fill=expt, group=expt)) +
  geom_bar(colour="black", stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width=0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = FC + se, ymin = FC, group=expt),
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width = 0.25)
```

[image]

or

```
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.5)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Gene, y=FC, fill=expt, group=expt)) +
  geom_bar(colour="black", stat="identity", position=dodge, width=0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = FC + se, ymin = FC, group=expt),
                position = dodge, width = 0.25)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not clear to me what controls the space between factors and the space between treatments.

Comment: i.e how would I adjust your code to keep the factors together but slightly decrease the spacing between them? Essentially your second illustration but with the spaces reduced

Comment: @fugu just increase both widths (position and bar) to, say, 0.7